# Update current data and add existing data to the updated data in Prisma

Tags: next.js, prisma

I am working with many to many realstion in Prisma with three table model

Schema:

```
model Student {
  id             Int     @default(autoincrement()) @id
  firstName      String  
  lastName       String
  classes        CourseEnrollment[]
}

model Class {
  id             Int     @default(autoincrement()) @id
  name           String
  courseDetails  String?  
  members        CourseEnrollment[] 
}

model CourseEnrollment {
  studentId      Int
  student        Student  @relation(fields: [studentId], references: [id])
  classId        Int
  class          Class   @relation(fields: [classId], references: [id])
  @@id([studentId, classId])
}
```

I would like to edit and update existing student and add a new class to that student if student have no class. I am able to manually update the data inside Prisma update and add existing class with class id.

Prisma edit:

```
  const result = await prisma.student.update({
    where: {
            id: 2
        },
     data: {
            firstName: "john",
            lastName: "james",
             classes: {
              create: [{
                class:{
                  connect: {
                    id: 25 //I tried add classId and set to just id
                  }
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        })
       res.status(200).json(result);
```

I am having problem doing this on the client side. I am able to console.log the data but how would I implement the functionality to edit data in the form?

my form:

//retrieve existing classes

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
const response = await axios.get(`/api/class/get/`);
    setClassData(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
        }
    };
fetchData();
});
```

save new data:

```
const handleSave = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
       const response = await 
     axios.post(`/api/student/update`, {
     id: parseInt(student?.id),
      firstName,
      lastName,
       classes: {
        connect: {
         id: classes.id //giving me error
        }
       }
      });
```

submit form:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSave}>
 <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" defaultValue {student?.firstName}/>
 <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" defaultValue={student?.lastName}/>
 <select name="course" id="course">
  <option value="">Select a class</option>
    {classData?.map((classes, id) => (
  <option key={id} value={classes.id}>
  {classes.name}
  </option>
    ))}
</select>
<button style={{ margin: "0 5px" }}>Save</button>
```

Comment: What exact error message do you get?

Comment: I'm getting invalide prisma.student.update() classes is not define or invalide argument.

Comment: You are trying to pass an array in nested create, do you want to create multiple entities while updating the student? You cannot create multiple entities inside an update query